# How do I find my internal ip address?

Tags: networking

I have Ubuntu server 12.04 installed, so I have no GUI. When I do the command ifconfig, I cannot find my internal IP address. It says: `inet addr: 127.0.0.1`.

Here is the output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0   link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:06:4f:4a:66:f0
    BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1   link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:ec:05:c8:9c 
    BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo     Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr 127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr:  ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536  Metric:1
    RX packets:1800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    Tx packets:1800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:143896 (143.b KB)  TX bytes:143896 (143.8 KB)
```

here are the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If someone could edit this for me, the contents of etc/network/interfaces should be on separate lines.

The output of host askubuntu.com was:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached.
```

I set up owncloud and webmin a few months ago and was using them for a month with no problems. I think the power went off one day 2 months ago and I never turned the server back on until yesterday. I haven't done anything that would have affected the internet setup So i'm not sure why it doesn't work anymore. As far as my network topology goes, I have a pci-e network card for the pc. The ethernet line goes from the network card to a switch, and then to a modem/router from there.

Comment: @AvatarParto Those are for interfaces facing public access, this question is about internal networks...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `/etc/network/interfaces` have in it?

Comment: I know how to use the change directory command, but I do not know how to list the files once there, how would I do this?

Comment: `ls` will list files in a directory. `ls -l` will give a detailed listing. To list contents of a particular directory, `ls -l /etc/network`. To change into a directory and list contents `cd /etc/network ;ls -l`. To read the contents of `etc/network/interfaces` (this is a file) `sudo pico /etc/network/interfaces`. (`pico` is a lightweight text editor - good for reading & basic editing, and less intimidating than `vi`.)

Comment: `ifconfig | grep -G "192.168.*.255" | cut -d' ' -f10` can get you the IP, or simply `hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1`

Answer (score 258, accepted):

These commands will tell you all network info

```
ip address
```

or

```
ifconfig -a
```

If as you say it only gives you 127.0.0.1 then there are two options:

1. Your network card is not attached or not recognized by the system
2. Your network DHCP server is not runnning or not connected

Comment: when I log in it tells me there are a few upgrades or updates, so I assume it has to talk to official ubuntu website to know it has updates, So i think my internet is working.

Comment: @Skateguy try to open askubuntu.com and please print all ifconfig -a

Comment: I have no GUI, i am about to type it out though.

Comment: How can I answer the questions that your two options pose?

Comment: @Skateguy First it seems you don't have a dhcp server and you will have to set your ip manually. can you tell us your network topology, how are you connected to the internet. and please post the output of the following command in your terminal: `host askubuntu.com`

Comment: `ip addr show` worked for me for ubuntu..

Comment: I would suggest the `ip` option _first_, then the ([deprecated](https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig)) `ifconfig` afterwards.

Answer (score 415):

```
hostname -I
```

This will give you just ip address without any extra information.

Comment: According to man page: `  -I, --all-ip-addresses
              Display  all  network addresses of the host. This option enumer‐
              ates all configured addresses on  all  network  interfaces.  The
              loopback  interface  and  IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted.`   So this will give you ip address on the network you're connected to , but also IP of your machine if you're using it as ethernet or lxd server. In my case it gives two addresses because I have lxd :  192.168.0.78 and 10.0.3.1

Comment: Yep. In my case it's more badly `10.0.2.15 172.18.0.1 172.17.0.1 172.20.0.1 172.21.0.1 172.22.0.1 172.19.0.1` because I'm running some Docker containers ;)

Comment: Upvote because other solutions don't work e.g. on raw docker ubuntu image

Comment: It appears to add an extra space at the end if you the final component has < 3 decimal digits. You can trim this with `| cut -d' ' -f1`, however.

Comment: exact answer. :)

Comment: I'd suggest `hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: when I do that , I got two ip addresses. Which is the one?

Comment: it gives more than one ip address

Answer (score 196):

This is what I currently recommend:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'
```

The advantage of that command is that you don't have to know which interface you are using (eth0? eth1? or maybe wlan0?), you don't have to filter out localhost addresses, or Docker addresses, or VPN tunnels etc. and you will always get **the IP address that is currently used for Internet connections** at that very moment (important when e.g. you are connected with both ethernet and wifi or via VPN etc.).

This will test not only that you have a correct IP configured on some interface (like with parsing the output of `ifconfig`) but also that you have the routing table configured to use it correctly.

I found that idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x#25851186)
by [Collin Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131881/collin-anderson).

I use it in the [internalip](https://github.com/rsp/scripts/blob/master/internalip.md#internalip) script in [my scripts collection on GitHub](https://github.com/rsp/scripts#readme), which you can install with:

```
wget https://rawgit.com/rsp/scripts/master/internalip
chmod a+x internalip
```

and use as:

```
internalip
```

or:

```
internalip TARGET
```

and you will get your IP address that would be used to connect **with the TARGET IP address**. The default target is `8.8.8.8` which is the [Google's public DNS resolver](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) and a good default for the Internet.

But if you run it with a different IP:

```
internalip 127.2.3.4
```

Then you will get:

```
127.0.0.1
```

because that is your IP address that would be used to connect **with 127.2.3.4** on the loopback interface. It's useful when your target is on a LAN, VPN or other special network, in which case some other IP could be used for connections than the default IP for reaching the Internet.

### External IP

To check your **external** IP address (the one that the servers on the Internet see when you connect to them - which may be different than the internal IP address described here) see [**this answer**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-bash/194136#194136).

Comment: This is a useful trick, but the OP was asking about an internal IP, so imay not be  not safe to assume that it's routable to 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @mc0e Good point. That's why [my script](https://github.com/rsp/scripts/blob/master/internalip.md#internalip) takes an optional argument for some other IP - `8.8.8.8` is just the default. In my answer I used `127.2.3.4` as an example. You can use some IP on your intranet or on a VPN as well. The point is that you don't usually have **one** internal IP address but few different addresses used for different targets. This way you can find the one that is actually used for connections to a given target.

Comment: Just so you know, this gives the external IP on Mac.

Comment: Recommended command prints `1000` for me on Ubuntu 20.10. I suspect this is because full result reads "8.8.8.8 via 10.1.1.1 dev enp2s0 src 10.1.1.30 uid 1000". Apparently, this is an over-complicated way to get your user id now!

Comment: In newer machines, use `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $7; exit}'`

Answer (score 19):

I think it worth mentioning that running ifconfig along with -a option will display all interfaces wether or not the interface has an IP.

running ifconfig alone, will display only interfaces with IPs assigned.

Here is a nice trick you could use to display only IPs using Perl.

```
# ifconfig | perl -nle'/dr:(\S+)/ && print $1'
192.168.1.100
127.0.0.1
```

Your network card is recognized by the system, that why its showing up eth0 and eth1

here is a quick way of assigning IP to your interface, use valid IP/Subnet accordingly.

```
 ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.200/24 up
```

then we need to add a default route

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

Best,

Comment: I would try this method but you will have to break it down a little more for me to understand it, as in how to find or know a valid IP, subnet and a valid default route.

Comment: this is a static IP assignment for your network interface, meaning if you are behind a router with subnet of 192.168.1.0/24 then you can ping an ip ex. 192.168.1.200 and if you get no response, then go a head and use ifconfig interface_name IP_ADDRESS/MASK up 

Your default gw needs to be added after assigning IP.

Answer (score 11):

This command will show all the IP addresses for a single device:

```
dev=eth0
ip addr show $dev | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

It will print one or two lines of output. The first one is the inet/IPv4 address and the other one is inet6/IPv6 if your system is configured to support this.

Answer (score 7):

In case, the `ifconfig` command didn't display the IP address, there is a very simple and easy way to find out the IP address of the Ubuntu machine through the GUI. Follow the steps below:

Click the **network icon** in the notification area and click **Connection Information**.
[image: Network icon options]

This brings up a window which has a some information, including the IP address.
[image: IP address information]

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of good answers here to choose from already, but I thought I'd point out [facter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/facter.8.html) which is usually, but not necessarily used with puppet for collecting various facts about the system.  The main advantage of facter is that it gives nice clean output which saves you all the manipulation with `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `cut`, `perl`, etc.  It isn't going to tell you which interface you're interested in, but if you know that, then the following gives you the IP without other cruft to clean up:

```
facter ipaddress_eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### ip command

Here's a variation on `ip addr` way.

`ip` has `-o` option which allows putting all information on single line - this is useful for parsing with tools like `awk` or `perl`. In combination with `-4` option, we will only see IPv4 addresses. Thus, output would be something like this (note - replace wlan7 with the interface you want to check):

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show wlan7
3: wlan7    inet 192.168.0.78/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan7\       valid_lft 85654sec preferred_lft 85654sec
```

As you can see, the IP address is 4th column/word in the output. The rest , is *simple parsing exercise* via the tool of your choice. Here, I'm using python:

```
ip -4 -o addr show wlan7 | python -c "import sys;print sys.stdin.readlines()[0].split()[3]"
```

Same thing, only with here string `<<<` and command substitution `$()`

```
python -c "import sys;print sys.stdin.readlines()[0].split()[3]"  <<< $(ip -4 -o addr show wlan7)
```

Personally, I have this saved as a nice function in my `~/.bashrc` so less typing is done.

```
wlan_ip() {
    ip -4 -o addr show wlan7 | python -c "import sys;print sys.stdin.readlines()[0].split()[3]" 
}
```

Perl's and Ruby's version are a bit shorter:

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show  wlan7 | perl -lane 'print $F[3]'                         
192.168.0.78/24

$ ip  -4 -o addr show wlan7 | ruby -n -e 'print $_.split()[3]'                 
192.168.0.78/24
```

#### Wireshark

If you're familiar with using network analysis tools, you probably know that to get your ip address, all you need to do is clear the browser cache, start Wireshark capture on the specific interface, and look for http `GET` packets being transmitted. The destination column will show your ip address

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of good info above.  I keep it simple like so:

```
# what your computer thinks its ip address is
function iplocal() {
  ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'    # 8.8.8.8 is google dns
}
# what the outside world thinks your ip address is
function ipexternal() {
  curl --silent http://checkip.amazonaws.com        # or:  http://ipinfo.io/ip
}
function ipinfo() {
  echo "local    IP  =>  $(iplocal)"
  echo "external IP  =>  $(ipexternal)"
}
```

Sample usage:

```
> ipinfo
local    IP  =>  192.168.1.139
external IP  =>  76.88.85.95
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still having issues with finding your ip addres can simply use `ip addr`

it will list all the network devices, that are connected to your computer, for example in the case of OP, there are three devices connected, but it seems that none of these devices are up, the `eth0` and `eth1` are ethernet devices (sockets) but as you can see these devices have not been assigned any `inet` address's.

```
eth0   link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:06:4f:4a:66:f0
    BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1   link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:ec:05:c8:9c 
    BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo     Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr 127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr:  ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536  Metric:1
    RX packets:1800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    Tx packets:1800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:143896 (143.b KB)  TX bytes:143896 (143.8 KB)
```

whenever you will connect to an ethernet or wifi, you will be assigned an ip address and following is an example of how it will look like

```
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1410 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:95:07:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.133.25/20 brd 172.31.143.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe95:7a5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

See in my example above, the device is an `ethernet` connection, and it has been assigned `inet` address

---

### How to read the information provided by `ip` command

at first glance, if you are not familier with networking this might seem very absurd to you, but its very clear, in the second line you will see `inet` this is your ip address - in my case its `172.31.133.25` and its written in `CIDR` Notation, 20 is there as a subnet mask bit, which you dont have to worry about

So in above case your ip address is just `172.31.133.25`

For some `ip` might not be provide a very good looking or informative response so you can install `net-tools` using

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

this will install `ifconfig` and `ifconfig` will show you things a little clearly like following

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1410
        inet 172.31.133.25  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.143.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe95:7a5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:95:07:a5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 238  bytes 223167 (223.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 145  bytes 12170 (12.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

You can clearly see `inet` is set here and subnet mask is written not in CIDR notation, but differently

In both the cases above ipv6 is also mentioned as `inet6`.