# Getting I.P address of Ubuntu Server running in Virtual Box

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS in VirtualBox. I would like to get the I.P address, and according to https://askubuntu.com/a/430855/192526, you do so with

```
ip addr show
```

It says

> inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host

So it would seem like I have an issue with my network adapter. However, I don't really know what settings am I supposed to be using:

[image]

What do I do to be able to get my actual I.P address from Ubuntu Server running in VirtualBox for Mac OSX?

I ask this because eventually I will want to setup an NTP server, and I imagine that a remote computer will need the I.P address of my Ubuntu Server.

---

By request, here is what `ifconfig` says:

[image]

---

Another curious thing:

When booting, there is a message saying

> Waiting for network configuration...

that lasts for quite a long while until it apparently gives up saying

> Booting system without full network configuration

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: What does `ifconfig` show you about your devices?

Comment: @Lucio sorry, that's 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: @robobenklein I've added a screenshot now

Comment: Does Bridged mode do what you want to? It would share your physical device. Just select `Bridged` from `Attached to:`

Comment: I guess you have a wrong network configuration. [This is my result](http://i.imgur.com/xvI0a2W.png) (took off the boring stuff).

Comment: @robobenklein: `Bridged` seems to show the same I.P as well.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have an IP address because you have not configured one.  To do so you need to edit /etc/network/interfaces.  If you want one to be obtained automatically, add eth0 to the auto line in the file, and add a new line for it that reads `iface eth0 inet dhcp`.  You can then reboot or run `sudo ifup -a` to bring up the interface and obtain the IP address.  See `man interfaces` for more information.

Comment: I have opened the file, and turns out that the modifications were already there. I executed `sudo ifup -a`, but the resulting I.P seems to still be the localhost. I should mention that, when booting, there is a message saying `Waiting for network configuration...` that lasts for quite a long while until it apparently gives up saying `Booting system without full network configuration`

Comment: Could it possibly be that those lines are the conflict? I know that a Network manager cannot manage the device if it is set in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @robobenklein, network manager isn't used in a text mode server install.

Comment: I've searched about the `Booting without full network config` thing, and this page http://sandilands.info/sgordon/old-creating-a-virtual-network-of-linux-guests says I should modify some lines of `70-persistent-net.rules`. However, my file is completely empty.

Comment: @psusi Yes, I know that, but I'm talking about the equivalent management done when the device is never specified in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @robobenklein, there isn't any equivalent management.  Either you have network manager installed, or you configure it in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: @psusi Interesting enough, new question about it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/555608/how-is-a-device-managed-when-not-in-etc-network-interfaces-on-servers

Answer (score 3):

I used "About This Computer..." menu item to get computer's name and later `ping` command to get its IP. I hope this will be helpful for you.
[image]

Comment: hmm... dunno but on 18.04 that is gone..... where the heck it is and why in the fucking hell they keep making these annoying change ? Are microsoft engineers involved in this ?
Click on the top left (Activities) then type "About this " to search and there it will be.