# Ubuntu Server running in Virtual Box - Network not connecting to Wifi bridged adapter

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 server on (Windows 10) VirtualBox (Version 5.0.16 r105871 ) by following the steps on here:  http://twoggle.com/blog/lamp-local-development-environment-virtualbox/

I selected Bridged adapter under the virtual machine's network settings:
(I am on wireless Wifi connection, which is connected OK on host system - I can access internet OK)

[image: bridged adapter selected]

But the network adapter connection is not working: During Ubuntu server load, when it gets to network load, it waits for network config for a long time then gives up eventually:

[image: Cannot find network connection]

After running ifconfig (once logged into Ubuntu), it has no IP address under the eth0 section.

I tried applying psusi's answer on here:
[Getting I.P address of Ubuntu Server running in Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555584/getting-i-p-address-of-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtual-box) but similar to the original poster on that question, the entry for eth0 already exists in network/interfaces file. 
I also do not have a 70-persistent-net.rules file on my ubuntu system at all.

I've not had these troubles before when directly plugged in with Ethernet cable to the network, only on Wireless. I am not able to use a Ethernet cable at the moment and must use wireless.

Any help much appreciated, this is very frustrating!

Comment: When I select NAT under Settings > network (for the VM), after I log in and I do a ifconfig, I do get an IP address for eth0 but when I try and ping this IP from cmd.exe (on the host), it times out ...

Answer (score 5):

OK got it working using this mega helpful post:
http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox
Note that only address 192.168.56.102 worked (not ending in .101 - must have caused a conflict with something else)

Answer (score 0):

I found excellent some of the explanations in here: [chapter 6](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

[image]

There are/were some know limitations when using WiFi bridged adapter as you experienced these.

Honestly, host-only is the great solution if you just need to have the communication with the host machine.

Hopefully this helps.