# How to Assign an I.P. address to a Virtualbox Appliance?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

How do I configure a VirtualBox appliance to have its own I.P. address when running on a host Ubuntu machine?

I've tried following the solution for this question but am not having any luck: [Getting I.P address of Ubuntu Server running in Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555584/getting-i-p-address-of-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtual-box)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your virtual machine adapter as `Bridged Adapter`.

Boot into your Ubuntu VM and run following command to get your IP address.

```
hostname -I
```

Now you can use ssh to access your server with that IP address or open-up website from your browser if you're running any web server.

If you want to add local network to your server aswell, then add Network Adapter 2 as `Internal Network`

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add static adapter as `eth1`

```
auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.0
```

When this is done, bring your adapter up.

```
ifup eth1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found another way via "Host-Only Adapter" as well.  File -> Preferences -> Network -> "Host-Only", "+" (adds the new i.p. address called 'vboxnet0' by default).