# How do I know my IP address?

Tags: 14.04, ip

How can I see my IP address on Ubuntu? I used

```
ifconfig eth0
```

but it only displays `HWaddr` and I don't see where the IP address is.

Comment: If there is no IP address in ifconfig, then you do not get one. Please [edit] your question and add output of `ifconfig` command.

Comment: And why eth0? Post just `ifconfig`.

Comment: Relevant https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address http://askubuntu.com/q/95910/178596

Answer (score 9):

The following command will output all of your current IP addresses, separated by spaces:

```
hostname -I
```

Answer (score 6):

Your best to use `ifconfig` without the interface as it may not be `eth0`.

```
ifconfig | less
```

will allow you to page down to see what interface is assigned an IP.

You can also cheat by using route to see what interfaces are being used.

```
$ route
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.138.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
```

and then use `ifconfig` on the interfaces listed, eg.

```
ifconfig eth2
```

Comment: Why sudo and why less?

Comment: +1 but I second A.B., `sudo` shouldn't be needed

Comment: I would use less because sometimes there maybe several networking devices including interfaces, aliases, bridges, tunnels.

Answer (score 3):

Use command: `ip addr show` and look for your interface, for example wlan0 for WiFi and eth0 for network card.

Comment: This seems to be installed by default where ifconfig may be missing.

Answer (score 1):

If `ifconfig` doesn't show an IP the interface doesn't have one assigned. Assign one with `sudo ifconfig 1.2.3.4 netmask 255.255.255.0` or use `dhclient -d [iface]` if you have a DHCP server in your network (if your uncertain try it, it doesn't hurt and is easier if it works).

Comment: You can additionally use `ip addr` to see all address (hardware, IPv4, and IPv6) assigned to an interface. (`ifconfig` is deprecated.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're connected to the network through a wireless NIC, `ifconfig eth0` is useless, because it will show the output of `ifconfig` for the first ethernet NIC (if any):

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

Or `wlan1`, `wlan2`, `wlan3`, [...] depending on how the NIC in use has been mapped (in case you have multiple wireless NICs).

To display only the IP address:

```
ifconfig wlan0 | sed -n '2s/[^:]*:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: But only with `LANG=C`. My german system says `inet Adresse` ;)

Comment: @A.B. Fair point ;) switched to the good old `sed`. That should match any possible language

Comment: I think, `ifconfig` is enough, +1

Comment: @A.B. What do you mean? Without `wlan0`?

Comment: It's also possible, that OP has `eth1` or any other thing

Comment: @A.B. That's true, updated

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use `nmcli dev show` (15.04) or `nmcli dev list` (14.04 and earlier). It lists full information about your interfaces, dns, nearest access points,  and of course your IPv4 address. You can use `awk` to trim the info as desired.

Comment: Yeah, `nmcli` =)

Answer (score 0):

After typing

```
ifconfig eth0
```

your IP should be listed under

```
inet addr
```

Something like:

```
inet addr:10.0.2.15 Bcast: 10.0.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
```

In this example, 10.0.2.15 would be your IP address.

Comment: There's no IP displayed if the interfaces doesn't have one assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Show all your IPv4 addresses:

```
LANG=C ifconfig | awk -F: '/inet addr/ {gsub(/ .*/,"",$2); print $2}'
```

Or for IPv6:

```
LANG=C ifconfig | awk '/inet6 addr/ {print $3}'
```

Or an other version:

```
ip addr show | awk '/inet/ {print $2}'
```

---

If you **only** see something like this:

```
127.0.0.1/8
::1/128
```

than you have no IP address.
(127.0.0.1 doesn't count as this is your system aka localhost.)

---

*Sample output*

```
% LANG=C ifconfig | awk -F: '/inet addr/ {gsub(/ .*/,"",$2); print $2}'
192.168.2.131
127.0.0.1

% LANG=C ifconfig | awk '/inet6 addr/ {print $3}'   
fe80::92e2:baff:fe21:c902/64
::1/128

% ip addr show | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' 
127.0.0.1/8
::1/128
192.168.2.131/24
fe80::92e2:baff:fe21:c902/64
```

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see the `LANG=C`

Comment: @kos not?, the first part. o_O

Comment: No, I jumped right on the right part of the pipe, because I was sure there would have been just `ifconfig`-something somewhere on the left! My bad