# How to know the Server's Public IP Address on Wireless Interface?

Tags: 16.04, broadcom

I want to setup a web server by using my wireless interface. Just wanted to know for testing purpose as I have setup LAMP. I'm connected to Internet through Wifi and at the same time I want to serve a website.
I am following this website to setup LAMP:
"https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04"

Where they told me to know "Server's Public IP Address" After entering the command it shows:- "Device "eth0" does not exist" as I'm using my Wireless Interface. Someone clear me this concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find my internal ip address?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address)

Comment: `ifconfig` show the connected LAN and WLAN IP addresses. But these may be private IP address because you said it is a Wireless Interface. Not the public IP address I think. That mean you can access that IP from your internal network but not from external network by other users.

Comment: @Vivek Mahajan Do you want to allow access to your server from WAN ?

Comment: Your public IP Address is probably not your IP Adress on your Wireless Interface. From your question it's unclear what you want. `ifconfig` or `hostname -I` will help you with WLAN Interface.

Answer (score 2):

To find your public IP Address, either search google.com: https://www.google.dk/search?q=find+public+ip+address or use http://www.whatismypublicip.com/ or similar service.

Answer (score 1):

As a 2021 addition to the answer given by Soren A, you do indeed need to use a service hosted on the (external) internet to get your public IP.

I like the site [ifconfig.me](https://ifconfig.me/) since one can use it with command line tools. I usually use `curl ifconfig.me`.