# RDP to my laptop from my PC both running ubuntu 20.04 over wifi?

Tags: 20.04, rdp

Here we go. I got my laptop, which I want to be accessed from my PC. Both run Ubuntu 20.04.
The same private WIFI network is used by both devices.
How can I achieve that?

So my goal is to:

1. Run my PC.
2. Connect to my laptop with GUI.
3. Be able to manipulate my laptop from my PC in realtime with benefits of few screens I got attached to my PC and high quality image.

Comment: Have you tried Remmina which comes with Ubuntu by default?

Comment: I am not sure how should I setup it as RDP server, which ports are to be exposed and how would I determine correct IP adress, that can be found by my PC as connection target.

Comment: You find your ip address as outlined in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/430855/307670) answer to a similar question.

Comment: @User24601, please, be attentive. That question asked not by me.

Comment: Oups, my bad eyes... sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDP is usually notation for Microsoft Windows Remote Desktop.

But you can try VNC.

On the "server" device, the laptop, open `Terminal`:

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
sudo ufw allow 5900/tcp
x11vnc
```

Edit: If you get error like `XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.` and it fails, try running `DISPLAY=:0 x11vnc`. Shouldn't be an issue with graphical edition (Desktop), but thought to mention it if someone else trys it in other circumstances.

See more details eg here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-share-your-desktop-in-linux-using-x11vnc

To see local IP open `Terminal` again and type:

```
ip a
```

Look for something like `inet 192.xxx.xxx.xxx` or `inet 172.xxx.xxx.xxx` (can be 10. as well, but usually its 192.). That's your IP.
Also in Terminal try

```
hostname
```

That's name of your laptop.

On "client" device, your PC:

```
sudo apt install tigervnc-viewer
```

Enter either `IP` or `hostname` of your "server" laptop, port `5900` (default), and try connecting.

Also, make sure firewall is setup, that's what "`ufw allow 5900/tcp`" did, but could be other firewall (unlikely), or local/hardware firewall (also unlikely, but have to mention it).

If that works, you can setup a password and other parameters.