# Where is the Internal IP address stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, files, filesystem, ip

Is there some file in the Linux-Ubuntu filesystem that contains the internal IP of the machine running it? Ideally, is the output provided by the following command

```bsh
hostname -I
```

saved somewhere in the filesystem?

(thanks to [How do I find my internal ip address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address?newreg=b2980c112c324147a4d43f522d44d199))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a tree in `/proc/net/fib_trie`

Otherwise you can look it up with a tool such as `ip addr`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there another file that contains the public IP?

Comment: @AndrewSpan no. There's simply no way a host can know this. In complex configurations the answer may be multiple. At work internet egress depends on country, target and protocol for instance.