# Printer IP Address entry in Terminal

Tags: printing

I've just installed a Brother MFC-J870DW printer in Ubunbu 20.04.  After printing a test page successfully while in terminal, I'm being asked to "enter ip address". Where can I find the information needed to enter?

Comment: Type "lpinfo -v" to see local name then "ping" it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find my internal ip address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address)

Comment: On my brother printer, you can display the IP address from the printer’s menu buttons - I think there’s a ‘network menu’ option on your printer’s control panel - should be fairly easy to display it from there I think.